# Is it possible to downgrade DrRacket without reinstallation or use an older compiler/interpreter version?

Tags: racket

I'm currently using DrRacket version 7.1. I want to be able to use an older version of the compiler/interpreter without having to reinstall the program.

The point is that I'm getting a different behaviour of the eval function in comparisson to my universitys script.

Edit: I am using Windows 10 OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's very easy to install multiple versions of Racket simultaneously.

Specifically, Racket's default installation is self-contained in the sense that all of its files go in a single directory, with optional links in standard places. I currently have 18 versions of Racket installed on my machine.

In order to give you a better answer, though, it would help a lot to know what OS you're using...

EDIT: Well, Windows is the platform I know the least about :). Nevertheless, it should be possible to simply download the desired version and install it. I would expect this to result in two fully-working DrRacket installations.

Comment: Ty for your answer. I knew that there had to be a way to change it :). I am using Windows 10 OS

Comment: So how do you do that in windows :)?

Comment: By just downloading the other version and running the installer? Am I understanding your question correctly?

Comment: have you tried downloading and installing another version without deleting the first one?

Comment: BTW, on an entirely different note, I'm assuming that you're *required* to use the eval function here? If not, my advice is much simpler: don't use eval.

Comment: Thanks for ur efforts. I like the "By just downloading the other version and running the installer?". I feel like a total idiot :(. I have to use the eval function because my professor used it in his script. I just repeat the same things ...

Comment: I'm sorry... I clearly phrased that badly. My apologies. I can't tell from your comment whether you tried it, and whether it worked?

Comment: I was just joking, its all fine. I downloaded the version 5.0 of racket and installed it. I opened DrRacket (not Racket) and it still seems to be the Version 7.1 of Racket. I m looking for some menu in DrRacket to set the current Racket version. Do you mean that I have to download an older version of DrRacket (and not Racket)?

Comment: I'm guessing that both versions are now installed, but that you started the 7.1 version rather than the 5.0 version. I would expect the 5.0 version to be in its own folder within C:\Program Files. I would use File Explorer to look in C:\Program Files\ and find the folder containing the newly installed 5.0 version.